# Where to handle duplicate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, duplicates, hook, pre

I am trying to figure out where is the best place to handle duplicates before inserting in mongoose.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        const doc = await User.findOne({ email: this.email }).exec();
        if (doc) {
            throw new Error('Email already used');
        }
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

The probleme is that when I want to update the username for example.

```
async function updateUsername(id, username) {
    try {
        const doc = await User.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
        if (docs) {
            doc.username = username;
            await docs.save();
        } else {
            throw {
                msg: 'Does not exist'
            };
        }

    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

This fires the pre hook and throws email already exists error.
I think im handling this in the wrong place... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type:String,unique:true}
    email: String,
    password: String, });

you can use unique:true while writing schema
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing this before but I didnt have any error, but now im having it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Schema level `validations` is

```
  const UserSchema = new Schema({
        username: String,
        email:  {type:String,unique:true},
        password: String,
    });
```